# C fgets strtok and atoi to read a line in C

Tags: c, fgets, strtok, atoi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[10000],*token;
    int garden[100],i=0;
    fgets(string,10000,stdin);
    token = strtok(string," ");
    while(strcmp(token,"\n") != 0){
        garden[i] = atoi(token);
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this code ? Why can't I read space separated integers from a line ?

Comment: If token is not found `strtok` returns a null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 while(strcmp(token,"\n") != 0){
```

to

```
while(token != NULL){
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only works when there's a space after the final number. Otherwise `strcmp()` never returns a non-zero value and you proceed to call it on a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: I have a newline after my line

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in the following way:

```
token = strtok( string, " \n" );

while ( token != NULL && i < 100 )   
{
    garden[i] = atoi( token );
    i++;
    token = strtok( NULL, " \n" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Igor already answered your question but please, consider alternative solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0, garden[100];
    while(i < 100 && scanf(" %d", &garden[i++]) == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if that will work the way he wants it to work i.e. reading numbers when the user inputs them separated by spaces without pressing '\n'

Comment: The problem with your solution is that `\n` is ignored and the only way to stop the input is Ctrl+D which can be a good thing. I see your code works fine if that is taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
int garden[10000],length = 0,i;
char string[100];
fgets(string,100,stdin);
char *token;
token = strtok(string," ");
while (token != NULL) {
  if(strcmp(token,"\n") == 0)
    break;
  garden[length] = atoi(token);
  token = strtok(NULL," ");
  length++;
}
for(i=0; i<length;i++){
  printf("%d ",garden[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

This code worked perfectly. fgets unfortunately reads the newline as well. So had to take care of that.