# how to read integers from a string that are separated by space

Tags: c, arrays

in the text file it'll say something like this:

12 4 23 76

7 3 12 54

1 54 2 67

...

```
int arr[26];
int arr2[26];
int arr3[26];

int main(){
fp = fopen ("myfile.txt", "r");
  while (fgets(store, sizeof(store), fp)){

    //I tried using scanf but I couldn't get it to work

   printf("%s", store); //prints out a line
  }

}
```

I know that the 'store' has the string that I want to work with. 
how can I grab the integers from 'store' that are separated by space and put them into an array?
so I would want

arr[0]=12 arr[1]=4 arr[2]=23 arr[3]=76,

arr2[0]=7 arr2[1]=3 arr2[2]=12 arr2[2]=65,

arr3[0]=1 arr3[1]=54 arr3[2]=2 arr3[3]=67

Comment: Have you looked into `sscanf`?

Comment: I've tried using it but I wasn't able to make it work exactly...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C, parsing a string of multiple whitespace separated integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233450/in-c-parsing-a-string-of-multiple-whitespace-separated-integers)

Answer (score 0):

you can use strtok() and atoi() function if string format is guaranteed.

here's draft of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int arr[3][26];
char store[100];
char *split;
int i, j;
int main(){
    i = 0;
    FILE* fp = fopen ("myfile.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(store, sizeof(store), fp)){
        printf("%s", store); //prints out a line
        split = strtok(store, " ");
        j = 0;
        while(split) {
            arr[i][j++] = atoi(split);
            split = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            printf("%2d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

I hope that you can utilize this code for what you want.

-> I fixed code which is able to run.

you can modify this code because I tested and it worked.

I'm not sure which point you struggled, but I suggest you to check out how to use those functions in web.

Comment: I tried it, however when I do printf("%d\n", arr[I][j]); after the split = streak(NULL, " ");, it only prints out 0s

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191011/c-fgets-strtok-and-atoi-to-read-a-line-in-c here's similar code! I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

the code posted by ChangHo is pretty accurate barring a few corrections.

Since the data contained in the text file, seems to contain blank lines, the primary fix is to ensure that these lines are ignored.

I notice in your comment, that when you try printing the vales after "strtok", you notice 0s.That's because the **value of the variable "j" has been incremented**....And is yet to be assigned a new value.....

```
arr[i][j++] = atoi(split);// j has been incremented
split = strtok(NULL, " ");
printf("%d\n", arr[i][j]);//displays 0,since "j" is yet to be assigned a value
```

All in all, here is the updated version of the code posted....
Please see the comments......

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arr[3][26];
char store[100];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
char *split;

int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen ("test.txt", "r");
  while (fgets(store, sizeof(store), fp)){
    if(strlen(store) == 1)//When fgets returns just the newline character
    continue;             //skip the line             
    printf("%s", store);  //prints a line
    split = strtok(store," ");
    j = 0;
    while(split != NULL){
      arr[i][j] = atoi(split);
      split = strtok(NULL," ");
      printf("%d\n", arr[i][j]);//print value in array before j is incremented
      j++;
    }
    arr[i][j] = '\0';//terminate the sub array with the NULL character
    i++;
 }
  //print the result
  for(int i  = 0;i<3;++i){
    for(int j = 0;arr[i][j] != '\0';++j)
      printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
  }
fclose(fp);
}
```